# Why does LaTeX push the text so far down the page?

Tags: margins, report

I am writing a report for a Uni project. We are a group of six, and I am in charge of the LaTeX part. I have a problem where the text starts 3/4 of the page instead of (ca.) at the very top. What can I do to fix it? I have tried \vspace*{-ncm}, I have googled margins and padding, and I have tried backtracking without help. This is the top markup:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}

% To prevent "Chapter N" display for each chapter
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Huge}

\begin{document}

% Prevents paginating the first page
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\begin{titlepage}
    \centering
    \vfill
    
    \huge \textbf {Title} \\ Made by: [names]
```

This is how it looks:

[image: LaTeX]

I assume the fix here will also help me narrow down that gap between "Contents" and the table of contents. Much appreciated!:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have posted a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) so I am not sure what the problem is — anyhow, that space is a space the standard `report` class puts at the start of any chapter, and the table of contents is treated as one.

[image]

I tested it with the following MWE:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% To prevent "Chapter N" display for each chapter
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Huge}

\begin{document}

% Prevents paginating the first page
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\begin{titlepage}
    \centering
    \vfill
    
    \huge \textbf {Title} \\ Made by: [names]

\end{titlepage}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter}

\lipsum

\section{Section}

\lipsum

\chapter{Another chapter}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

If you call `titlesec` (see its manual, page 2, "Spacing") with

```latex
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
```

and add (page 5. spacing)

```latex
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-2cm}{0.5cm}
```

you have a slightly more compact layout (which I think feels cramped):

[image]

**HOWEVER**, if you want to tweak the appearance of your document more, the best way is to choose another class or use a high configurable one like for example `memoir`.

Comment: It worked! I ended up going with titlespacing in the end. Thank you my friend, and from now on I will read the documentations more thoroughly :)